# getting 'True' value instead of real value when trying to append in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, append

Below is my python script.I am trying to parse an xml file and trying to store values in pandas dataframe so that I can later change it to csv file.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import sys
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom

tree = ET.parse('schedule.xml')
FILENAME = sys.argv[1]
COL_NAMES = ['PODNAME', 'DC', 'Upgrade']
DF = pd.DataFrame(columns = COL_NAMES)
root = tree.getroot()

def parseXml(DF, filePath):

    xmldoc = minidom.parse(filePath)
    PODs= xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("POD")
    name=[]
    DC=[]
    deferUpgrade=[]
    for pod in PODs:
        if pod.hasAttribute("name") and pod.hasAttribute("DC") and pod.hasAttribute("deferUpgrade"):
            DF = DF.append({'PODNAME': pod.getAttribute("name"), 'DC': pod.hasAttribute("DC"), 'Upgrade': pod.hasAttribute("deferUpgrade")}, ignore_index=True)
    return(DF)


DF = parseXml(DF, FILENAME)
```

Below is the XML file

```
<Schedule xmlns="http://xmlns.xyz.com/fal/downtimeschedule/V1.0">
 <Downtime end="20181020000" id="10001197610_20181027000_201810000" mode="cold" start="20181020000"/>
 <PODS>
  <POD DC="US - Washing" deferUpgrade="true" name="ABCD" patching="Production" EndTime="20181028040000">
   <CR id="12345"/>
   <CR id="12346"/>
   <CR id="123"/>
  </POD>
  <POD DC="US - Washing" deferUpgrade="true" name="ABCD-TEST" patching="Production" EndTime="20181028040000">
   <CR id="12345"/>
   <CR id="12346"/>
   <CR id="123"/>
  </POD>
 </PODS>
```

when I am running my script with first argument as filename I am getting below output

```
     PODNAME    DC Upgrade
0       ABCD  True    True
1  ABCD-TEST  True    True
```

However, I expect below output.

```
     PODNAME    DC            Upgrade
0       ABCD  US - Washing    true
1  ABCD-TEST  US - Washing    true
```

Also, I tried to use concat to overcome above issue but getting below ouotput

```
       PODNAME              DC Upgrade
0       [ABCD]  [US - Washing]  [true]
1  [ABCD-TEST]  [US - Washing]  [true]
```

Comment: You might wanna try getAttribute for all three intead of just first column, in your if block.

Comment: `pod.hasAttribute("DC")` returns a boolean, try `getAttribute("DC")` as you did with name.

Comment: thanks Nitin & Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nitin and Martin replied, pasting final code here.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import sys
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom

tree = ET.parse('schedule.xml')
FILENAME = sys.argv[1]
COL_NAMES = ['PODNAME', 'DC', 'Upgrade']
DF = pd.DataFrame(columns = COL_NAMES)
root = tree.getroot()

def parseXml(DF, filePath):

    xmldoc = minidom.parse(filePath)
    PODs= xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("POD")
    name=[]
    DC=[]
    deferUpgrade=[]
    for pod in PODs:
        if pod.hasAttribute("name") and pod.hasAttribute("DC") and pod.hasAttribute("deferUpgrade"):
            DF = DF.append({'PODNAME': pod.getAttribute("name"), 'DC': pod.getAttribute("DC"), 'Upgrade': pod.getAttribute("deferUpgrade")}, ignore_index=True)
    return(DF)


DF = parseXml(DF, FILENAME)
```